# Using web browser and putty for developing web-server on WSL

Tags: webserver, windows-subsystem-for-linux, putty

Can I use putty and web-browser for testing my web-server code in Linux ?
I'm using WSL with Ubuntu18.04 , it's very convenient to use it because I'm using vs code as IDE ...

So to test my code i need a putty (as a client) and the web-browser to run my code on ...

Answer (score 1):

You can run tests on localhost. I think WSL shares the same IP address.

Comment: same for putty and web-browser ?

Comment: If you just want a way to test your web dev you can **run python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000** on your WSL, then you should be able to use putty to send whatever files you want to test. Im not 100% sure I dont use putty. Then on your windows OS in your web browser go to http://localhost:8000 to view it.

Comment: works , only for p3 the module has merge to http.server .
so command is : " python3 -m http.server 8000"

Answer (score 0):

We can use web-browser with loaclhost for testing webserver on wsl .
We can test it by running on wsl this:  "python3 -m http.server 8000"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).